# RSpec Delayed Expectation Argument Matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I currently have some rails code in a controller that does something like this:

```
def update
  @local.update(...)
  @local.save!
  Exchange::publish_to_exchange('event-title', Serializer.new(@local).serializable_hash)
  render ...
end
```

I want to test that the message has been published with the correct message name and the serialized, updated object. So, in the controller spec I do something like this:

```
let(:local) { create(:local_class) }

it 'publishes serialized version to exchange' do
  expect(Exchange).to receive(:publish_to_exchange).with('event-title', Serializer.new(local).serializable_hash)

  put :update, params
end
```

However, this obviously doesn't work because it is comparing the unupdated, serializable hash of local with the updated version. I'm wondering if there is anyway to delay the checking of the matcher after  the "put :update, params," line, so that I can test this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to test that the message has been published with the correct message name and the serialized, updated object...

That is not really appropriate for a controller test, since the publishing occurs outside of scope of the controller action. If you need to write a unit test for it, you are much better off putting that test in the model, or in a separate unit (like a PORO loaded from `lib`).